# Motivation behind $X$ is an affine variety if and only if $I(X)$ is a prime ideal.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is not so difficult to prove that for any affine algebraic set $X$, $X$ is an affine variety if and only if the ideal $I(X)$ is prime. But I seem to be completely lacking the motivation behind this result. It would be great if someone could provide the algebro-geometric motivation behind this crucial fact.

Comment: As in the answers below, the real mathematical substance is that we want _irreducible_ "varieties"... so slightly-obscurely "define" "variety" to include "irreducible".

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity fix a field $k$ over with the affine space $\mathbf{A}^n$ is defined. The idea here is that a variety $X \subset \mathbf{A}^n$ is always defined to be irreducible, i.e. it is not the union of two smaller spaces that are closed in the Zariski topology. And being an irreducible subspace $X$ in $\mathbf{A}^n$ is the same as requiring that the ideal sheaf $I_X \subset k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is a prime ideal.
In scheme theory, this concept is going to be generalised.
$\textbf{Edit}$: Or think of it this way: if you study manifolds, every property you'd study you study on its connected components. If it is not connected, you restrict to one component. The same here: If $X$ is reducible, i.e. its ideal sheaf $I$ looks like a product $fg$,for polynomials $f,g$,  then $X=V(f)\cup V(g)$ and you could study both vanishing sets separately.

Comment: But I think this result existed before scheme theory and someone must have had the motivation (excluding divine inspiration) to come up with this result.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifZaheer not sure what you are asking! If the set is not irreducible, then study each irreducible component.

Comment: I think it's clear that $X$ must be an irreducible algebraic set (affine variety) in order for the equivalence in the question to hold.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifZaheer a priori you don't need scheme theory to understand it. Edited the post slightly

Comment: @MuhammadAtifZaheer if you like this reply, please accept the answer. Otherwise feel free to ask more!

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is an affine variety then it is plausible to think that if the product $fg$ vanishes on $X$ then either $f$ or $g$ must also vanish on whole of $X$ as $X$ is small (cannot be decomposed into smaller algebraic sets). The motivation for the converse is also similar.